# Javascript: Data Object merging

Tags: javascript, object, merge, element

I am wondering if there's a way to merge an element in an object if they have same property.

Here is what I mean:

```
var dummy = {
 data: [
     {name: 'A', info: '1'},
     {name: 'B', info: 'A'},
     {name: 'C', info: '2'},
     {name: 'A', info: '2'},
     {name: 'B', info: '2'}

  ]
};

var expected_results = {
 data: [
  {name: 'A', info: '1,2'},
  {name: 'B', info: 'A,2'},
  {name: 'C', info: '2'}
 ]
}

//Todo if same name merge if not seperate
var plugin = {
 unique: {
    list: []
 },
  merge: function(params) {
   var lists = plugin.unique.list;
   lists.push(params[0]); //First always unique
   $.each(params, function(index, item) {
      if(index !== 0) {
         $.each(lists, function(index, list) {
            if(list.name === item.name) {
               list.info += ',' + item.info;
            } else {
               lists.push(item);
            }
         })
      }
   })
   return lists;
  }
 };

console.clear();
var list = plugin.merge(dummy.data);
console.log('result',list);
```

I think I'm close but not quite sure where whent wrong with my loop...:(

Comment: Yes. Give it a go yourself first and let us see your code.

Comment: there is not a built-in method for this, but you can write code to do it, yes.

Comment: Almost *anything* is possible.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you haven't showed any effort to do it yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be honest, if you're going to be grouping by key you might as well use an object rather than an array as your returned data structure. Much easier to manipulate.

```
function squish(dummy) {

  // pass in an initial empty object
  // if the key isn't there, create it and use an array
  // as a value - push in the value
  var out = dummy.data.reduce(function (p, c) {
    if (!p[c.name]) p[c.name] = [];
    p[c.name].push(c.info);
    return p;
  }, {});

  // flatten the arrays for each key
  Object.keys(out).forEach(function (el) {
    out[el] = out[el].join(',');
  });

  // return the expected_result
  return out;
}

squish(dummy);
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/q05pk0vo/1/)

OUTPUT

```
{
  "A": "1,2",
  "B": "A,2",
  "C": "2"
}
```

But, if you really want to have an array of objects, that's simple enough too:

```
function squish2(dummy) {
  var out = dummy.data.reduce(function (p, c) {
    if (!p[c.name]) p[c.name] = [];
    p[c.name].push(c.info);
    return p;
  }, {});
  return Object.keys(out).map(function (el) {
    return { name: el, info: out[el].join(',') };
  });
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/q05pk0vo/5/)

OUTPUT

```
[
  { "name": "A", "info": "1,2" },
  { "name": "B", "info": "A,2" },
  { "name": "C", "info": "2" }
]
```

Comment: Thanks Andy! Appreciate your help, was using jquery and loop but yeah didn't know about the other function in javascripts. 

Great help, thanks again!